# Deslocamento de coluna no bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Estou montando um código para *colunar* uma lista de produtos.

Cada linha tem 4 colunas e pula para a próxima linha.

Mas quando por exemplo, a altura da primeira coluna é maior que as outras e eu redimensiono a janela, a primeira coluna da segunda linha, se desloca pra frente.

Segue abaixo um trecho do código. Será que alguém pode me ajudar?

```
<% Do While not rs.Eof
   <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6" align="center">
       <div class="col-lg-12" align="center">
          <img src="images/produto/nome.jpg" class="img-rounded img-responsive">
       </div>
       <div class="col-lg-12 size-font-10-normal" align="center">Titulo</div>
       <div class="col-lg-12 size-font-09-bold" align="center">Valor</div>
   </div>
<% rs.MoveNext
Loop %>
```

[image: Imagem de Exemplo]

Comment: Se tem sempre 4 colunas poderia usar um "clear" no primeiro ítem de cada linha. Veja se algo disso ajuda: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/16897/70 ou mesmo http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42714/70

Comment: Utilize código fonte ao invés de imagens, dependendo da qualidade da imagem, pode dificultar a visualização do código fonte.

Comment: Toda vez que essa pergunta vai pro começo da fila me dá uma dor só de ler o título. Deslocamento de coluna deve doer pra caramba.

Answer (score 1):

Crie uma Class css para os item, e defina um height para esses itens.

Deste

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6" align="center">
   <div class="col-lg-12" align="center">
      <img src="images/produto/nome.jpg" class="img-rounded img-responsive">
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-12 size-font-10-normal" align="center">Titulo</div>
   <div class="col-lg-12 size-font-09-bold" align="center">Valor</div>
</div>
```

Mude para esse:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 item" align="center">
    <div class="col-lg-12" align="center">
        <img src="images/produto/nome.jpg" class="img-rounded img-responsive">
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-12 size-font-10-normal" align="center">Titulo</div>
   <div class="col-lg-12 size-font-09-bold" align="center">Valor</div>
</div>
```

No seu arquivos de css da pagina adicione esse stylo

```
.item{
  height : 130px; /*leve em consideração o tamanho que você acha adequado*/
}
```

Comment: É o que eu faria também pra solucionar o problema.